# What is the largest hard drive a Mac Pro 3,1 (early 2008) will support?

Tags: hard-drive, mac-pro, virtualization

What is the largest internal hard drive a Mac Pro 3,1 (early 2008) can support?

I [read here](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_pro/specs/mac-pro-eight-core-2.8-2008-specs.html) that it's around 1.2 TBs is that correct?  Also I plan to run Proxmox on it, not Mac OS X (well, I might run it as a VM, but not directly on the bare metal).

Comment: I have several 3TBs in mine. Never tried anything bigger.

Comment: I'd go to OWC to see: http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Seagate/STBD6000100/. They may have more but that was what I found with a quick search.

Comment: @bassplayer7 Not sure how that helps - Yes, it's a big drive, but it's SATA III not II. It also won't directly fit an old Mac Pro without a mounting kit.. for which they want 25 bucks when you can get one from eBay for a fiver.

Comment: oooh... after just seeing this flagged as 'correct' I have more info to add, learned only recently, I'll drop it into the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any upper limit, but after checking more carefully, in mine I have

- 1 x 3TB
- 3 x 2TB
- 1 x 1TB [SSD in the spare optical bay, wired down into the 'secret' extra SATA slots]

**Late addition**
It appears that there is not necessarily a data limit but a physical limit.
New 6TB+ drives have the screw-holes in a different place & will not physically fit the HD sleds in a 3,1.
So it turns out that the limit is 4TB - the largest with the old screw-placement.

You can get replacement sleds for a 4,1 or 5,1 from OWC, but not for the 3,1

Comment: and all hooked up at the same time ? not just a collection

Comment: Yes, they're all in right now & in use, along with an SATA DVD drive I also retro-fitted to the 'secret' SATA ports [best price for a PATA was £100, SATA equivalent £15 inc postage - I made it work;)

Comment: Why would anyone need 10 Terra B of storage :) that is 40x more than what I have ! What are you saving if I my ask.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I'm a composer/audio engineer. I have TBs of audio sample data & for movie scores etc I need to separate movie streaming from sample data to prevent playback hiccups. Keeping things on separate drives helps. My most-used sample sets I keep on SSD too. One of those 2TB drives is Time Machine [without samples], plus I keep my sample sets duplicated over 2 drives [& on Backblaze] in case of failure.

Comment: any good stuff to listen to :)

Comment: hehe - lots, but I'm waaaaaaay off-topic ;-) A teaser - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9m2mmvk7zlo

Comment: so what are you doing here? it is wonderful.

Comment: I learned 'how to do computers' in the 80s, because of my musical interest & how the field was changing. My job in the 90s was based on that agglomeration of knowledge. Now I feel it's time to 'hand back' some of that, since i'm pretty much retired otherwise. I never stopped doing one to accomplish the other :P

Answer (score 0):

I just added a 6TB drive. I doubt I will ever need to go bigger than that. I see 12TB drives out there, and don't know why they shouldn't work.

Mac OS X supports drive sizes up to ~8 EB (Exabytes).

Comment: I remember the day I spent $300 on a 3GB (yes GB) drive, and thought I never fill it. Now, I can't count how many single files I have that are larger than that. A 2-1/5 hour rock concert backed up from the TiVo is 21GB. You might respond that a packrat can fill any space, and that may be true, but how many times have you seen a set of shelves next to a TV loaded with VHS tapes or DVDs? At least all my video is hidden on a few hard drives.

Comment: My first ever HD was 650MB, yup, the capacity of a CD. It cost £800, circa 1986